# Multiple Feature Branches With Continuous Integration - Deployment

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, branching-and-merging

We are using SVN to develop and there is no opportunity to switch as we are in a large company that wont allow it.

The client/server application that we are developing gets built and deployed nightly using TeamCity so that the next day users/testers/devs can test the latest code. Due to the nature of the system, some parts have to be deployed in order to be tested. e.g. the server side part, Swing GUIs, new config that needs storing in a db before it can run etc.

This is fine when everyone is committing to trunk. However, after we have a code freeze and go live we need to switch to a different model. We are considering branching per feature then merging several branches back to make a release.

This is good for keeping the code clean, but how can we do the manual testing for each of the features? We don't have enough hardware to deploy every single feature branch. Even if we did it would be tedious to test as you would have to log in to multiple environments to see all the latest features.

Would it be possible to have a staging branch that TeamCity auto-merged into from several of the feature branches?

This is mentioned for DVCSs so doesn't really apply
http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/10/automatic-merge/

What are my other options?

Have everyone commit to a dev branch that gets built manually then cherry pick from there to trunk when ready to go to UAT then live, then create a new dev branch from trunk and cherry pick the other commits that didn't make it to UAT?

Comment: What solution did you end up going with?  I find myself in a similar situation as the one you described.  The project I am working on now has been doing Trunk Based Development with SVN for a couple years and has just recently started doing basic CI/CD via TeamCity and Web Deploy (.net mvc web app).  Management now wants to starting doing isolated feature branches and I am looking for best practices.

Answer (score 0):

One popular solution to feature branches in CI is,

1. Commit your work to your branch
2. Have a CI box listening to that branch repository to run a basic set of checks (Compile code, run all unit & component tests, quick smoke tests)
3. If that succeeds, Merge the latest from trunk into your working copy
4. If the Merge is successful without conflicts, commit the working copy to trunk
5. Run the rest of integration and system testing on the new release candidate from trunk

The idea is, you release as often as possible. Taking each thing in trunk as production ready

Two of the main problems with this approach are;

1. Having a CI technology with feature branching support (Else you will be configuring new Pipeline configurations for each feature)
2. Svn Merging can be a bit of a pain compared to newer tools like Git. You just got to work on smaller change sets, update from trunk frequently and have smaller classes

Comment: Are the merge steps here manual or automatic? How would you do it automatically? I am assuming a build failure on merge conflicts.

Comment: I would attempt to automate it first, it depends on the build tools you use. If a conflict is found, a Build failure should be thrown.

If you update the feature branch from trunk before code commit, the probability of Merge conflicts in the pipeline should be reduced.